# Finding the next instance of a non-sibling child in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I have a form with inputs and and div container outside of form with help text for each input.

```
<form>
    <input id="name" />
    <input id="email" />
    <input id="pass" />
</form>
<div class="help-container">
    <p class="help-name"></p>
    <p class="help-email"></p>
    <p class="help-pass"></p>
</div>
```

Now the .help-container is initially hidden with { display: none; } as well as each child p.

The jQuery I'm having trouble with is:

```
$("form").find("input").focus(function(){
    var parent = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).closest("form").next(".help-container").show();
})
```

1) This does not work. Why?

```
$("form").find("input").focus(function(){
    var parent = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).closest("form").next(".help-container").show();
    $(".help-container").children("p").hide();
    $(".help-container").children("p").find(".help-" + parent).show();
})
```

2) This does not work. Why?

Comment: `parent` is a keyword in JavaScript. While it's not a reserved word per se, I would definitely avoid using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are your issues

```
$("form").find("input").focus(function(){
    var parent = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).closest("form").next(".help-container").show(); // you show the container
    $(".help-container").children("p").hide(); // hide all p under it - nothing is shown now
    $(".help-container").children("p").find(".help-" + parent).show(); // you're trying to find elements under p with class .help-xxx
})
```

You need to change it to this

```
$("form input").focus(function(){
    var parent = $(this).attr("id");
    $(".help-container").children("p").hide();    // hide all p's
    $(".help-container").children("p.help-" + parent).show(); // show relevant p - since you want the p with the matching class
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vjUme/

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. Optimizing jquery is not my strong suit.

Answer (score 2):

This line wont work:

```
 $(".help-container").children("p").find(".help-" + parent).show();
```

because you are searching for .help-ID **inside** the `p` element, try this instead:

```
 $(".help-container").children("p.help-" + parent).show();
```

Comment: Thank you. Among other things I was applying the ids in divs instead of the p and didn't notice. Stupid...

Answer (score 2):

**[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ufacoq/1/edit)**

```
$("form").find("input").focus(function(){
    var helper = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).closest("form").next(".help-container").show();
    $(".help-container").find(".help-"+ helper ).show().siblings('p').hide();
});
```